# Are there any online resources to verify death of a inmate at Fort Leavenworth?

Tags: military-records, death-records, imprisonment, kansas, 1970s

One of my cousins asserts that her Uncle died "in prison" at Fort Leavenworth Kansas on 1 Jan 1976.

Are there any online resources that would verify the death of a prisoner (assuming that he was actually a prisoner)?

Would one expect that Kansas would issue a death certificate?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question but -- Do you know where he is buried? If he was buried outside Kansas, there may be a certificate in the state where the cemetery is located. See https://www.legalgenealogist.com/2015/01/21/death-in-the-wrong-place/

Comment: Is he in the [Social Security Death Index](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/ssdi/)?

Comment: @Bill, yes... he is -  however in the index it does not say where he died, only his birth, death dates SS# and date claim filed.

Comment: Newspapers.com has Leavenworth, Kansas newspapers, but I don't know if they reported on things that happened in the prison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to access them until 2048.

Federal prison records less than 72 years old are exempt from the Freedom of Information Act under subsection (b)(6). To quote from National Archives guidelines, "this type of record might include medical information, personal financial data, Social Security numbers, intimate details of an individual's personal or family life, or similar data."

Copied from US Archives "Searching Inmate Case Files from the U.S. Penitentiary at Leavenworth, Kansas"